# how can use listModel.get(position) in Activity?

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener

how can use listModel.get(position) in Activity?

In the Adapter onBindViewHolder, I can use listModel.get(position) to get values, but how can do it in Activity?

this is my coed

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.personal_feed);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        listUserFeedModel = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        getData();
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
        adapter = new NewUserFeedAdapter(listUserFeedModel, this);
        getIncomingIntent();

account_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //check whether it is liked or unliked

                //Log.d("CHECK",listUserFeedModel.get(i).getFeedFollow());
                if (listUserFeedModel.get(i).getFeedFollow().equals("1")) {
                    //update unlike drawable
                    account_follow.setText("Follow");
                    listUserFeedModel.get(i).setFeedFollow("0");
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i, "0");
                    unfollow(getIntent().getStringExtra("pid"),memail);
                } else {
                    //update like drawable
                    account_follow.setText("Followed");
                    listUserFeedModel.get(i).setFeedFollow("1");
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i, "1");
                    follow(getIntent().getStringExtra("pid"),memail);
                }

            }
        });
}
```

I got the error "error: cannot find symbol if (listUserFeedModel.get(i).getFeedFollow().equals("1")) "

[image]

so how can solve this problem?